# Passing arguments to selector

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

i have been working on a small demo and i wrote a function which accepts two string object and looks like this

```
-(void)adding:(NSString*)num1 :(NSString*)num2
{
    num1 = first.text; //first is object of label
    num2 = second.text; //second is object of label

    int x= [num1 integerValue];
    int y = [num2 integerValue];

    int r = x+y;
    NSLog(@"%d",r);
}
```

am having one more function

```
-(void)calling
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(adding:)withObject:@"num1" withObject:@"num2"];
}
```

and am calling the method named calling on button touch up inside event

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(calling) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but i get an error called unrecognized selector sent to instance

can you please tell me where i am wrong and how to pass methods with arguments to selector.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a colon. Try this :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(adding::)withObject:@"num1" withObject:@"num2"];
```

However, it's bad form to have unnamed parameters on your method names because errors like this happen ;)

I'd rename your method to be

```
-(void)adding:(NSString*)num1 to:(NSString*)num
```

and have this line :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(adding:to:)withObject:@"num1" withObject:@"num2"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You got your selector wrong, it should be `@selector(adding::)`

Also in this case you don’t need to use `performSelector:...`, you can send the message directly: `[self adding: @"num1" : @"num2"]`.